# Tried to create my own python module with multiple functions, but it won't load because of SyntaxError

Tags: python, function, module

I have created two different functions within the same file `twitter_functions.py`.  The purpose of first function (`import_tweets`) is to load Twitter data into a list.  The purpose of the second function (`most_freq`) is to count the most common authors and hashtags from the first Twitter data.

In attempt to keep things modular, I would like to call `import_tweets` to import my data when running `most_freq`.  However, when I try and load this module with the two functions into python, I get the following error:

```
import twitter_functions as tf
  File "D:\python\twitter_functions.py", line 76
    hashtags = [i['text'] for i in hashtags]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried everything down to individually commenting out line of my code, and I still throw some sort of error when trying to import my `twitter_function` module.

When I had just had the first function (`import_tweets`) by it's self in my module (`twitter_functions`), it worked just fine.  And I know the `most_freq` code worked fine as well.  I just must be missing something when trying to put them together in the same module.  Ideally I would like to add additional functions to my `twitter_functions` module, but need to figure out what I'm doing wrong here before I dream up those functions.

```
import json
import time
from collections import Counter

def import_tweets(input_file):
    """
    Loads JSON data from Twitter Streaming API for analysis.

    Parameters
    ----------
    input_file : JSON file from Twitter Streaming API

    Returns
    -------
    List of nested dictionaries
    """

    # Load JSON data into a dict    
    data = []
    for line in open(input_file):
        try: 
            data.append(json.loads(line))
        except:
            pass

    # Transform Twitter tweet date/time format into standard date/time format
    for i in data:
        i['CREATED_AT'] = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.strptime(i['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'))

    return data


def most_freq(input_file):
    """
    Counts the most frequent users and hashtags

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : output from import_tweets

    Returns
    -------
    Top 10 most frequent users and hashtags
    """

    # Load data from import_tweets
    data = import_tweets(input_file)

    # Create list of all tweet authors
    authors = [i['user']['screen_name'] for i in data]

    # Create a list of all hashtags
    hashtags = []
    for i in data:
        if ['entities'] in i:
             hashtags.append(i['entities']['hashtags']
    hashtags = [i['text'] for i in hashtags]

    print Counter(authors).most_common(10)
    print Counter(hashtags).most_common(10)

    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a closing `)` on the *preceding line*:

```
 hashtags.append(i['entities']['hashtags']
 #              ^                         ^
 #               \- opened, not closed --/
```

Python sees the next line as part of this statement because the `.append()` call is not yet closed, but `hashtags` on the next line is not valid statement to follow `i[...][...]`.